# Can Facebook group admins see the location of people who contact them to join their group?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-messenger, facebook-groups, facebook-privacy

I messaged a group admin requesting to join their private group and the admin was able to see my location (albeit it wasn't my actual location because I was using company server).

I was using my phone and location is turned off on both fb privacy and on the phone.

How was that possible?